# How to stop the multiple API request in react js functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new in react js. I have a function and one GET API request. I need to dispatch the API action in the functional component. When I call the `dispatch` function in my functional component. It's re-render multiple times (Multiple requests coming). When I use the `dispatch` inside the `useEffect` My API is not dispatched.

Without `useEffect` `dispatch` function called:(API called multiple times)

```
export default LogoCard {
    let id=1;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(viewLogDetails(id));
}
```

using `useEffect` `dispatch` function called.(`dispatch` function not called using `useEffect`)

```
export default LogoCard {
    let id=1;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(viewLogDetails(id));
    },[dispatch]);
}
```

Redux Action:

```
export const viewTimeLogging = createAsyncThunk(
    "logoReducer/logo/Viewlogo",
    async (id, { getState }) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`/viewLogDetails?id=${id}`);
        let data = null;
        data = await response.data;
        return data.viewLogo;
    }
);
```

Comment: How did you tell the action is not dispatched?

Comment: I added the dispatch function in useEffect. But the Dispatch function is not called.

Comment: The dispatch function is executed using useeffect. But, In my redux action I get the state information, That time not getting state information. So, My API was not called

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the method you are calling inside your dispatch has a different name.

- If you need the axios method to be called only when id changes you should use the useEffect hook with [dispatch, id] dependencies (I assume that you will pass the id as a props or gather it in some other way in the future instead of having hardcoded like that).
- If you want to call the dispatch on every re-render of the component you can either put it inside the function like the first piece of code you wrote (but I would not do that).

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-raman-tul4j?file=/src/App.js
Here's a sandbox with the code you might want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).